# Windows iot LCD screen for raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

Please apart from the 7" LCD touch screen, which other lcd screen can work with raspberry pi using windows iot core operating system

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the screen device which is listed in the [Hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist). As mentioned in the document, this list is not exhaustive. There are many other peripherals not listed on this page that are compatible with Windows 10 IoT Core. You may try with other screen, maybe it is also compatible. If you just want to use a display screen without touch input, in general the screen with HDMI interface is usable.